# How to use phone calls without code?

Tags: calls, hardware, sim-unlocking

My friends and family need to use my cellphone regulary, it doesnt bother me, because some of them cant have a cell but still need one just in case...the problem is that i dont want them to have access to my apps, notes, texts private infos etc... is there a way for them to use my cellphone (just for making calls) without having access to everything in my phone? Thank you

Comment: Depending on the phone/manufacturer/ROM you are able to use the multi-user feature to access the guest account that does not have access to your main user.

Comment: You can also use "kiosk mode" after opening the Phone app if you're running 5.0+.

Comment: As a third option, you could download an app lock application, which allows you to block any app with a pin/pattern. This way, you could seal anything but the dialer.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Go the Google Play and download this app. If it isn't exactly what you are needing, get back to me and I'll find something more appropriate for your needs. Is your phone rooted? That helps a lot when you are wanting to customize your device. You can find plenty of info at XDA-Developers.com  Here is your link to the app. If you need any thing else, just ask. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.privacylock.guest&hl=enk.